# Will Windows 10 work in my computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, user

Will Windows 10 work in my computer?  Now using Windows 7 Home Premium Service Pack 1, Processor is Intel Core i7-2600CPU@3.40GHz,RAM is 12GB, hard disk space-20GB for 64 bit OS, Graphics card is AMD Unified 8.921.5.6000 RevA 137.0Mb

Comment: Go to Microsoft Downloads and get (download) the Microsoft Windows 10 Upgrade advisor application. Run this on your computer and see what it tells you and report back here so we may help

Comment: @John, I dont think there is one. I should install just fine on that hardware.

Comment: Try this site:  https://www.intowindows.com/download-windows-10-upgrade-advisor/   Also if you try to install Windows 10, there is a question "Check if this PC will run Windows 10 . They have integrated it into the installation but it does check requirements.

Comment: Be aware that Windows 10 is no longer a free upgrade in 2020/

Comment: *Windows 10 is no longer a free upgrade in 2020* That's not true. Windows 7 (non-cracked version, of course) is freely updated to Windows 10 using Upgrade Advisor 1803. Then one may use Upgrade Advisor 1909 for to upgrade to most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

Official Windows 10 System requirements are:

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4028142/windows-10-system-requirements

- Processor: 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster processor or SoC
- RAM: 1 gigabyte (GB) for 32-bit or 2 GB for 64-bit
- Hard disk space: 16 GB for 32-bit OS or 20 GB for 64-bit OS
- Graphics card: DirectX 9 or later with WDDM 1.0 driver
- Display: 800 x 600

If I've read it correctly, you are using a 20Gb HDD. If so, beware that these are the minimum system requirements, which means allocated disk space for Windows 10 might be larger than 20Gb.